# Getpivotdata in loop results in run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get Pivot Table data from a table and enter values into region. I can get the data on test, but the same operation within a loop results in a run-time error 1004. Please see the code below, and again thanks to everyone for their time. Have a nice day

```
Sub Pivot3()

Dim targetregion As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rCell As Range
Dim key As Variant
Dim test As Variant

Set pt = Workbooks("OPEX.xlsm").Worksheets("Opex_main").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set targetregion = Range("J2:J19")


'testing whether I can get pivot data
key = 71010080
test = pt.GetPivotData("SumOfValues", "CC_Grouping", "xyz", "GL", key)
MsgBox test
'end of test, all good here

For Each rCell In targetregion
        If rCell.HasFormula Then

        Else
            key = Cells(rCell.Row, 7).Value
            MsgBox key  ' testing if key was properly loaded for the row, all good here

            'here the problem occurs, yet it is same as few lines up
            test = pt.GetPivotData("SumOfValues", "CC_Grouping", "xyz", "GL", key)

            MsgBox test  'testing if correct value was loaded from pivot table
            rCell.Value = test
        End If
Next rCell


End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `key` is not of the proper type when pulled from the cell?  Or that there is an extra space or something else along those lines?

Comment: Yes you are right. Setting initial test value to `key = Range("G7").Value` gives same error on first test. So this is where the problem lays

Comment: Ok, problem is in source pivottable. I need to find a way how to write it, so if there is no value found in pivottable, it skips to next rcell. Thank you for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. At least it acts as expected, and nothing wrong showing up so far.
Err.Clear within the loop, so where it hits run-time error 1004 second time, it is able to load it into Err. That's how I understand it

```
Sub Pivot3()

Dim targetregion As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rCell As Range
Dim key As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim group As Variant

Set pt = Workbooks("OPEX.xlsm").Worksheets("Opex_main").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set targetregion = Range("J2:J19")


group = Range("A7")
For Each rCell In targetregion
        If rCell.HasFormula Then

            Else
                    Err.Clear
                    key = Cells(rCell.Row, 7).Value
                    On Error Resume Next                        
                    rCell.Value = pt.GetPivotData("SumOfValues", "CC_Grouping", group, "GL", key)

        End If

Next rCell

End Sub
```